# Imageresizer - watermark opacity

Tags: imageresizer

We need to apply watermarks, both image and text with an opacity applied.

It seems from the documentation that this is possible for images, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
imageQuery="filter=alpha(0.5)"
```

And there appears to be no option for text watermarks.  Am I missing something as I would have thought this would be a common requirement for watermarking.

Here is an example of what we are trying to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE7r7.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text layers can have an 8-digit color specifier. Opacity is the last two digits. I.e, FFFFFF99 would be a partially tansparent white.

```
<watermarks>
  <text name="test2" text="Hello #{name}!" 
   vertical="true" align="topright" color="FFFFFF99" />
</watermarks>
```

Comment: Oh thanks I will try that.

And the imageQuery option for the image layers?  Are you able to confirm that opacity (alpha) works there as I have not managed to get it to work.  Other imageQuery params work properly (eg. rotate) but not alpha filter.

Comment: I have confirmed that the opacity for text layer works.  And I got the image watermark opacity working by installing the SimpleFilters plugin.  Please consider adding both of these to the product documentation!